# multistep form php and jquery

Tags: php, forms, request, multi-step

Hello i am using step forms step1,step2 etc

here i apply jquery and goes to next page but my issue is i do not get data of first step in request on next step. here are just steps on sinlge page they just display hide and block.what should i do to get in php request  all step data till final step completed

```
<form>
<div class="step1">
<input type="text" name="firstname">
</div>

<div class="step2">
<input type="text" name="lastname">
<div>

<input type="submit" name="sub">
<input type="button" name="next">
<input type="button" name"previous">

</form>
```

here when

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your php implementation, but you have two options here:

1- using an ajax to send data back to the server after each step.
2- use separate page for each step.

Comment: Thanks for response.What do you suggest?

Comment: if you know javascript it's a much better to send the data back to the server using ajax, you can also find some jQuery plugins for multistep forms that can automate this process.

Answer (score 0):

While click the button in **step 1**,

1. You insert into the corresponding table and get the inserted id
2. Hold that inserted id value in some hidden type in a form.

While clicking button in **step 2**,

1. you need to update the respective column and its value in the inserted table row data with your id which you holded in your form

Continue the same process until your all steps get completed.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#next").click(function() {
             var currentStep = $('#currentStep').val(); // based on the step you need use some switch or conditional block to pass data and store it accordingly.
            // insertedId ==0 means you need to insert into table, if it not you need update the column in table

              var formdata = {insertedId:$("#insertedId").val(),currentStep:currentStep, first:$("#first").val()};

               $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "form.php",
                 dataType:'json',
                 data: formdata
                 })
                 .done(function( data ) {

                     var NextStep =parseInt(currentStep)+1;
                     $("#currentStep").val(NextStep);

                     $("#insertedId").val(data.insertedId);
                     $("#step"+currentStep).hide();
                     $("#step"+NextStep).show();

                 });
            });         
        });


    </script>
```

HTML:

```
        <div id="step1">Step 1:

            <input type="text" name="first" id="first" value="">

        </div>

         <div id="step2" style="display:none;">Step 2:

            <input type="text" name="last" id="last" value="">

        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="insertedId" id="insertedId">
        <input type="hidden" name="currentStep" id="currentStep" value="1">
        <button id="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: i have 30 to 35 fields at each step so if i take hidden fields it would be long.

Comment: I asked you to hidden the inserted id of your row only

Comment: at present i am using http://thecodemine.org/# which allow me to go to next and previous with proper validation but only issues is with form data does not passes at all stage.what is the easy and best solution ?

Comment: can you give me sample of that what exactly saying

Comment: Thats why I suggested, while click the next button itself, store into the database and move into another step. $('#next').click(function(){ $.ajax(function(){ });});

Comment: Thanks for reply that happens in my case i have button on clicking that it stores it in database the first step value but when i am on next step and clicking that button again it consider the first step values blank in request and update this blank data.is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: I have updated code, once step1 completed and stored, you can either hide that section and show next step or on ajax success you need to populate the value back into the form.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41386/discussion-between-vishal-and-chinnu-r)